# Javascript easing not animating

Tags: javascript, html, css, easing

Trying to implement simple easing in javascript (without jQuery) but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any animation when the button is clicked (see below).

My goal is to get the hidden list item (the last item) visible by tweening the first item's margin left property. I know it isn't a CSS issue because manually modifying the style moves the list, but I'm not sure what the issue is. My guess is with how I'm calling the ease function but changing the params still wasn't working for me.

The easing part is below, entire code is here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74gx6/1/)

JS:

```
var start = document.getElementById('start'),
    list = document.getElementById('my-list'),
    imgs = list.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    last_img = imgs[imgs.length -1 ];

    ease = function(t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
            return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },

    shift_imgs = function(el) {
        var orig_value = parseFloat( el.style.marginLeft ),
            end_value = -37,
            change = Math.abs( end_value - orig_value ),
            duration = 1, // 1 second
            time = 0;

        for ( var i = 0; i < change; i++ ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.style.marginLeft = ( parseFloat( el.style.marginLeft ) + 1 ) + 'px';
                }, time);
            time = ease(time, orig_value, change, duration);
        }
    };

start.onclick = function() {
    shift_imgs(last_img);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a CSS transition? You have [unlimited bezier functions](http://cubic-bezier.com/) at your fingertips ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes I am well aware of CSS3, but this is more of a person exercise :)

Comment: Fair enough! I have been through this exercise myself, so I fully understand :) But the main problem is that `margin-left:123` is not valid. The valid CSS is `margin-left:123px` - remember to add the unit, even in JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `orig_value` is `NaN` as `parseFloat(el.style.marginLeft)` returns nothing, even if you set an initial value in the css. i.e: `margin-left: 15px;` still will return nothing.

You can use [**window.getComputedStyle(...).getPropertyValue**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle), similar to this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
```

This will give you the actual current value along with the `px`, i.e: `0px`.
*(It always return the value in `px` even if set in CSS as `em` or `pt`)*

So you need to remove the `px` and the get the float value.

You can wrap this into a little helper similar to this:

```
getElementMarginLeftAsFloat = function (el) {
    var pxValue = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
    var valueOnly = pxValue.substring(0, pxValue.length - 2);

    return parseFloat(valueOnly);
}
```

Another issue is that the moving of the actual element occurs within `setTimeout` executed inside a loop. The loop which calls `setTimeout`, causes each `setTimeout` to be queued nearly simultaneously, hence they all execute close to the same time, causing the element to just jump.

You can use a recursive sub-method inside your method which uses `setTimeout` to call itself until it is done. That way each `setTimeout` is triggered only after the specified  interval, causing them to be executed close enough apart to the specified interval, similar to this:

```
shift_imgs = function (el) {
    var orig_value = getElementMarginLeftAsFloat(el),
        end_value = -37,
        change = Math.abs(end_value - orig_value),
        duration = 1, // 1 second
        time = 0;

    function doShift() {
        currentValue = getElementMarginLeftAsFloat(el);

        if(currentValue+1 > change){
            return;
        };

        el.style.marginLeft = (currentValue + 1) + 'px';
        time = ease(time, orig_value, change, duration);
        setTimeout(doShift, time);
    }

    doShift();
};
```

By having the `setTimeout` function call itself, it releases the resources, ensuring the drawing of the element can occur between each "iteration".

I updated your code to use this approach and it seems to work now.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWp85/) - animating movement using computed style

---

You can most likely do this many other ways and also prettify this code for sure but but this should get you started either way.

Comment: Great catch François on the typos! I updated the code and fiddle but unfortunately I'm still not seeing an animation. Could it be that moving 37px in 1 second is too quick for the animation to be noticeable?

Comment: @smaili: Ah yes, I see now that it just jumps. I miss-understood the expectation and assumed you clicked per pixel. Sorry about that. I have updated the answer now to ensure animation actually occurs. The for loop didn't work. the drawing of the element simply happened after the loop was done. I have replaced the loop with a recursive sub-method which keeps calling itself within a `setTimeout` instead, which causes the draw to execute each "iteration".

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Thanks Francois for the help and detailed answer!

Comment: @smaili: I also updated my explanation now on why the loop did not "seem" to work. A `setTimeout` in a loop does work in general, though in your example the loop executes so fast it queues up all the `setTimeouts` calls nearly at the same time with only a millisecond (maybe 2) in-between, hence they execute at the same time, causing the element to "jump".